# Woocommerce Columns Won't have a row more than 2?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For some reason, all of my products are stacking as 2, it doesnt matter if I change Columns-2/3/4/5 it always stays at 2 ?

If you just look my homepage you will understand, I think its a simple fix but I been trying for days now :(

http://www.motorbike-shop.co.uk/

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You should share your code here, not a link to your website. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your problem. It has to do with `clear:both !important;`, you can easly fix this bij using a `clear:none!important;` on your elements

For example:
This is located in the local.css at line 165

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1240px)
.page-template-template-fullwidth-php .site-main .columns-4 ul.products li.product, .page-template-template-homepage-php .site-main .columns-4 ul.products li.product, .storefront-full-width-content .site-main .columns-4 ul.products li.product {
    width: 22%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.347826%;
    clear: none !important; <- Add this rule!
}
```